# How to delete the rownames column from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to transfer rows from one table to another. However, one table has rownames while the other doesn't.

The error I get is:

> Incorrect syntax near the word 'from'

How to handle this situation?

Comment: Question is not clear can you post screen shots of tables and sample data

Comment: I have no idea what a "row name" is in SQL

Comment: Actually i solved it by putting '1' as rownames in code which deals with the table which doesn't have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2, Column3) 
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3    
FROM Table2    
WHERE Table2.Column1 = 'Test'
```

Answer (score 1):

IF the columns are same in the both the table :

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

If you want to transfer few rows but the the column names are different :

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3) SELECT (column1, column2, column3) FROM table1 WHERE condition;
```